# Localization in NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Hello I am trying to convert **декабрь/12/1982** date into **NSDate** but it will return nil value. Following is my code.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru_RU"]];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

 NSDate *dateCreated = [formatter dateFromString:strSelectedDate];
```

My application has multi language support.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `MM` is for a 2-digit month number. Use `MMMM` for the month name.

Comment: @rmaddy, Thanks for your reply but output which i need is 01/12/2015 so that's why i use MM/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: But your code is for converting the string to an `NSDate`. The format must match the string. If your then want to convert the `NSDate` to a new format, that's a 2nd step with a new format.

Comment: Your "strSelectedDate" should be in the same format as "MM/dd/yyyy".

Answer (score 2):

this works:

```
NSString *temp = @"декабрь/12/1982";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru_RU"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"LLLL/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *dateCreated = [formatter dateFromString:temp];
NSLog(@"%@", dateCreated);
```

output is: 216:27582] 1982-12-11 23:00:00 +0000